# How do I set the 'Enable tracing' preference in an RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, trace

I have an RCP application comprising of an number of plug-ins. Each plug-in contains an `.options` file containing trace information.

I would like to deploy the application with the `Enable tracing` preference set. This will enable tracing using the information defined in the option files.

How can I initially set the `Enable tracing` preference ?

**UPDATE**

I have tried following up on greg-449's answer but without success.

I created a custom.prefs file which is loaded using an entry in the `product.ini` file.

```
-Declipse.pluginCustomization=custom.prefs
```

custom.prefs:

```
org.eclipse.ui.editors/spacesForTabs=true
org.eclipse.ui.editors/tabWidth=3

org.eclipse.ui.trace/tracingEnabled=true
org.eclipse.ui.trace/tracingFilePath=atf.log
org.eclipse.ui.trace/tracingMaxFileCount=5
org.eclipse.ui.trace/tracingMaxFileSize=2000
org.eclipse.ui.trace/tracingEntries=tracingEntries=...my entries....
```

I added the editors prefs just as an indicator that the custom prefs were loading. When I view the editor preference page I see that the tab size is set to 3 and tabs replaced by spaces. However the tracing options remain unchanged - i.e. disabled

(I'm using Kepler and the product is based on plugins only)

Comment: Sorry by answer is out of date, there have been relatively recent changes I have looked at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tracing preferences page saves the preference settings in the `org.eclipse.ui.trace` preferences. So they are stored in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directory in the `org.eclipse.ui.trace.prefs` file.

You can set initial values for the preferences using a `plugin_customization.ini` file in your RCP. For example to enable preferences the entry would would be:

```
org.eclipse.ui.trace/tracingEnabled=true
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have tried but without success and added an update to the original question. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This [Eclipse bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496091) seems to be saying the tracing doesn't conform to the normal way of enabling things in the plugin_customization.ini  so it may be this doesn't work after all.